# Why does this code not work in counting sort problem in C?

Tags: c, algorithm, sorting

```
int *countingSort(int arr_count, int *arr, int *result_count)
{
    int i, j, s;
    int *res = (int *)malloc(100 * sizeof(int));  
    for (i = 0; i < arr_count; i++)
    {
        s = arr[i];
        res[s]++;
    }
    return *res;
}
```

I couldn't get any answer even while returning `res`. Can anyone explain the code for counting sort?

Comment: _I couldn't get any answer_ What do you mean exactly?  Do you mean that **no value at all** was returned?  Or do you mean that a **wrong** value was returned?

Comment: No value at all was  returned

Comment: The function does have a `return` statement, so I don't see how that is possible...

Comment: In any case, we'll need to see a **complete** example, including how the function is **called**.

Answer (score 3):

The code posted does not sort the array, furthermore the array allocated with `malloc()` is uninitialized so the code has undefined behavior.

If you can assume the values to be in the range 0 to 99, you do not need to allocate memory for the counters.

Here is a modified version:

```
int *countingSort(int arr_count, int *arr, int *result_count)
{
    int count[100] = { 0 };
    *result_count = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < arr_count; i++) {
        int s = arr[i];
        if (s >= 0 && s < 100)
            count[s]++;
        else
            return NULL;
    }
    int *res = malloc(sizeof(*res) * arr_count);
    if (res != NULL) {
        /* store the sorted numbers */
        for (int i = 0, j = 0; i < 100; i++) {
            while (count[i]-- > 0)
                res[j++] = i;
        }
        *result_count = arr_count;
    }
    return res;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The provided code for counting sort has several issues:

1.The res array is not initialized to zeros, leading to unpredictable behavior.

2.The return statement tries to return the value of the first element of res instead of the pointer to the array.

3.The result_count parameter is not being used or updated.

Here's a corrected version of the code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int* countingSort(int arr_count, int* arr, int* result_count) {
    int i, s;
    int *res = (int*)calloc(100, sizeof(int)); // Allocate and initialize to zero

    for (i = 0; i < arr_count; i++) {
        s = arr[i];
        res[s]++;
    }

    int count = 0;
    for (i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
        if (res[i] > 0)
            count += res[i];
    }
    *result_count = count;

    // Create a new array to store the sorted elements
    int *sorted_arr = (int*)malloc(count * sizeof(int));

    // Traverse the result array and place each element in the sorted array
    int index = 0;
    for (i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
        while (res[i] > 0) {
            sorted_arr[index] = i;
            index++;
            res[i]--;
        }
    }

    return sorted_arr; // Return the pointer to the first element of the sorted_arr array
}

// Example usage
int main() {
    int arr[] = {3, 1, 4, 1, 5, 9, 2, 6, 5, 3, 5};
    int n = sizeof(arr) / sizeof(arr[0]);
    int sorted_count = 0;
    int* sorted_arr = countingSort(n, arr, &sorted_count);

    // Print the sorted array
    for (int i = 0; i < sorted_count; i++) {
        printf("%d ", sorted_arr[i]);
    }
    printf("\n");

    free(sorted_arr); // Don't forget to free the dynamically allocated memory
    return 0;
}
```

Now, the countingSort function will return a sorted array. The output will be:

```
1 1 2 3 3 4 5 5 5 6 9
```

Comment: This code does not return a sorted array.

Comment: Can you please check now updated code now with output

Comment: The code works but you forgot to free `res`, and you would have undefined behavior if allocation fails or if the array contains numbers outside the range 0..99.